# How to prevent right click from deselecting marker in Kendo-UI

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

### How to distinguish between left and right click in legendItemClick kendo function?

I have an application that has a chart with time series data. The chart contains several markers that get highlighted whenever I hover over the legend. When I click on markers in the legend they are no longer highlighted in the chart. The click event is triggered and kendo's legendItemClick function is called. However when I right click on the legend item, a context menu appears, but the call to legendItemClick is still registered and thus the markers in the chart get deselected.

> Is there a way to prevent legendItemClick to be called on a right mouse click event? If not, then is there a way to distinguish between a left and right mouse click inside the legendItemClick function?

Here is the reference to the function I am using: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/events/legenditemclick

I tried searching for e.keyCode, but it is not a property.

Comment: See [MDN Web API Reference - MouseEvent.button](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/button).

Comment: @georgeawg I am dealing with a kendo ui chart element, not an html <button> so the event that gets passed into the legendItemClick function does not have a button property or a keyCode property.

Comment: Some APIs will expose the original event with the `originalEvent` property. Do a console.log of the event to inspect the event. Also inspect the event prototype.

Comment: @georgeawg I tried that, but unfortunatelly kendo api does not provides the original event.

Answer (score 0):

> unfortunatelly kendo api does not provides the original event.

One approach is to capture and save the original event before it bubbles:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", saveMouseDown, true);

function saveMouseDown(ev) {
    $scope.mouseDownEvent = ev;
}

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    document.removeEventListener(saveMouseDown);
});
```

The third argument to the `addEventListener` method specifies "capture" mode.

For more information, see

- [MDN Web Api Reference - addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Will this approach work for touch screen devices such as tablets? I need to figure out if the event was a right click and if it is prevent default behavior...