# Kendo UI Chart disable legend item right click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I have an application that uses a Kendo UI Chart with a legend. When the user clicks on a legend item, the Kendo `onLegendItemClick(e)` method gets called. However the event that gets passed to this function does not contain the `originalEvent`, so there is no way to distinguish between right and left clicks.

Here is the relevant API reference: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/dataviz/ui/chart/events/legenditemclick

I tried adding an event listener and capturing the 'mousedown' event before onLegendItemClick is invoked as shown below. However, this approach will fail on touch screen devices (iPads, tablets, mobile devices, etc).

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", saveMouseDown, true);

function saveMouseDown(ev) {
    $scope.mouseDownEvent = ev;
}

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    document.removeEventListener(saveMouseDown);
});
```

> The application has a separate directive for handling right clicks. Is there a way to prevent Kendo from calling the `onLegendItemClick(e)` method when a user **right** clicks the legend item?

Answer (score 0):

Add "click" to the list of saved events<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55577800/5535245)</sup>:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown click", saveEvent, true);

function saveEvent(ev) {
    $scope.savedEvent = ev;
}

$scope.$on("$destroy", function () {
    document.removeEventListener(saveEvent);
});
```

Related question: [How to prevent right click from deselecting marker in Kendo-UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55577800/5535245)

Comment: I used that response for my code but it failed on touch enabled devices. I will try this now. It's just unfortunate that we can't disable the onLegendItemClick method for right clicks. At least give us the originalEvent Kendo...

Comment: File a [new issue](https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/issues/new) with the Kendo-UI team.